# UIScroll View Paging

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have scroll view with page controll i have images in scroll view i want to save any image i want in sqlite data base problem is that always pageNumber shows only one

```
 here i am setting the current page Value 
       - (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)sender {

         CGFloat pageWidth = scrollView.frame.size.width;
           int page = floor((scrollView.contentOffset.x - pageWidth / 2) / pageWidth)  + 1;
         [pageControl setCurrentPage:page];


      }


     -(IBAction)addToCollectionButtonAction{




      GeoNewsAppDelegate *appDelegate = (GeoNewsAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication   sharedApplication] delegate];

   // Create a Coffee Object.
    Coffee *coffeeObj = [[Coffee alloc] initWithPrimaryKey:0];

    int pageNumber  = [pageControl currentPage]; 
    NSLog(collectionImage);


    RowTwo*aRowTwo=[appDelegate.articles objectAtIndex:pageNumber];
    NSString*thumb2=aRowTwo.image;

   coffeeObj.thumb = thumb2;
   coffeeObj.path = thumb2; 


    [appDelegate addCoffee:coffeeObj];
      }
```

Comment: Use this [Link][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963343/scrollview-with-pagecontrol-programmatically/5963534#5963534

Comment: simple i want to ask why pageNumber is always showing value 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should get your answer [here.](http://www.edumobile.org/iphone/iphone-programming-tutorials/pagecontrol-example-in-iphone/)